# Interactive routing track problems

Tags: pcb-design, altium

Why does Altium make track like this:
[image]

Instead of this:
[image]

Where in the settings it can be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Because you've drawn it that way. Pay attention to the draw route before clicking down a path.  Try different route settings (during interactive routing, press 1 or 5, or press ~ and see available options; or press TAB and check Routing Gloss setting).
2. Check Routing rules, including Routing Corners, and all SMT rules, most likely SMD To Corner or SMD Entry (this seems the most likely culprit).
3. Draw it fast and loose anyway, and edit it later by dragging segments around; use object hotspot snapping.

Comment: 4. use gloss routing command after routing.
5. place components on the grid